# Where is my executable when I install netCDF4 using anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, netcdf4

I installed netCDF4 using this command

`conda install -c anaconda netcdf4`

I see it has been installed when I do `conda list`

`netcdf4                   1.4.2            py27h808af73_0    anaconda`

But, when I try to get a link to the installed library, I get nothing.

`which netcdf4`

---

But, similarly, when I installed `jasper`, I do get the link to the exec.

```
conda install -c anaconda jasper
which jasper
~/miniconda3/envs/testenv/bin/jasper
```

---

The installed libraries have to be supplied for a configuration script of a model. I have not used `conda` for non-python library management much.

How can I get access to netcdf4?

Comment: what you installed is a python library with c-bindings: `netcdf4-python: python/numpy interface to the netCDF C library` (https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python). Maybe that was not what you were looking for?

Comment: NetCDF is a library and therefore you need to use `ldd` (linux) or `otool` (OSX) to locate it. `which` can only locate executables on your `PATH`.